# Is it possible to create a function pointer to the a function's `new` operator/constructor?

Tags: c++, new-operator, function-pointers, boost-bind

If I were to wanted to parameterize creating an object, I could of course make a function which called new on a particular class and passed out a pointer. I am wondering if it's possible to skip that step and pass a function pointer to the `new` operator itself.

Comment: `pass a pointer to the new operator itself`, What?!?

Comment: New is an operator that behaves like a function that takes returns a pointer the object you are creating. Conceptually (if not actually) it should be possible to create a function pointer to it, and pass it around as an argument to a function, for example.

Comment: Just as you think you would: `void* (*np) (size_t) = &::operator new;`. Is it just me or are the questions getting more and more Byzantine as time goes by? Bonus question: what happens when you `delete np;`?

Comment: @Kerrek, hm interesting. I suppose I should have said a function's new operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

boost::lambda provides [function wrappers for `new` and `delete`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.construction_and_destruction) These can be used to easily convert an `new` call into a function object.

Answer (score 2):

`operator new` (as well as the other flavours) takes care of allocating memory but does not construct objects. In fact its return type is `void*`. What constructs an object is a *new expression*, which is part of the language and not a function. So it's not possible to form a pointer or reference to it; it's as meaningless as forming a reference to `return`.

Comment: Perhaps not possible, but certainly not as meaningless as forming a reference to `return`.

Comment: Well, typically you'd use your custom new-pointer to allocate and then pass the result into a placement-new expression... that isn't entirely unheard of.

Comment: @Catskul You can't form a reference to a function to what is not a function. That's what is meaningless.

Comment: @Kerrek Notice that it's still a new expression constructing the object. And you can't form a reference to it because it's not a function.

Comment: @Luc: yes, of course, you cannot make a reference to the process of constructing an object. I'm not really sure what the OP is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Luc I don't disagree, but conceptually it has some sense. There are effectively functions being called behind the scene, malloc and then of course the constructor.

Comment: @Catskul You can say that of almost every expression possible: eventually, in most programs, functions end up being called. But let me clarify; when I say it's *meaningless*, I mean it's meaningless **according to the rules of the language**. For instance, `std::vector<42>` is meaningless. It was not meant as a comment on what you're trying to achieve, or yourself.